# VPN access with Junos Pulse Linux client + eToken?

Tags: linux, vpn, usb, credentials

Does anyone know whether the Junos PulseSecure client for Linux (5.3+) can use a USB token for VPN authentication, e.g., via pkcs11? I'm using a SafeNet (Aladdin) eToken 5110 on Windows. My impression from trying the Linux client is that it doesn't support it even though it is possible to access the credentials on the token via the SafeNet Linux drivers, but I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to the last page of the PulseSecure [5.3r3 quickstart guide](https://www.pulsesecure.net/download/techpubs/current/1055/pulse-client/pulse-secure-client-desktop/5.3rx/ps-pulse-5.3r3-linux-quickstart-guide.pdf), "client certificate authentication through smart cards is not supported." This seems to imply that tokens cannot currently be used either.